# Retriving Printer data from Windows with C++ fails

Tags: c++, winapi, printing

I'm trying to get printer information in Windows 10 with a simple Visual Studio console project.  But the call for GetPrinter() does either throw an exception (of unknown type) or returns fail with GetLastError() giving 87.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```cpp
int main()
{
    PRINTER_DEFAULTS pd = {};
    pd.DesiredAccess = PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS;

    HANDLE hPrinter;
    WCHAR pname[] = L"KONICA MINOLTA C368SeriesPCL";
    if (OpenPrinter( pname, &hPrinter, &pd) == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    PRINTER_INFO_2 printerInfo = {};
    
    DWORD bytesNeeded = 0;
    GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, 0, 0, &bytesNeeded); 
    // bytesNeeded is now aprox 9k

    printerInfo.pDevMode = (DEVMODE*)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, bytesNeeded); // pointer seems valid

    /* uncommending this call throws an exception - do not kno why */
//    if( !GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, (LPBYTE)&printerInfo, bytesNeeded, &bytesNeeded))
//        return 1;

    /* this call does not throw but fails with GetLastError() returing 87 */
    if (!GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, (LPBYTE)&printerInfo, bytesNeeded, NULL))
        return 1;
 
   return(0)
}
```

Comment: Get rid of `PRINTER_INFO_2 printerInfo = {};` and do:
`PRINTER_INFO_2* printerInfo = (PRINTER_INFO_2*)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, bytesNeeded);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4th parameter of `GetPrinter` should be size of structure (buffer) at which 3rd parameter points. 5th parameter returns required size of buffer (not `sizeof`)!

```
 DWORD bytesNeeded = 0;
 GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, 0, 0, &bytesNeeded); 

 PRINTER_INFO_2 *printerInfo = (PRINTER_INFO_2*)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, bytesNeeded);
```

The function requres addtional memory to allocate  strings and structures pointed by `PRINTER_INFO_*`s members. It's `GetPrinter`s responsibility, not yours.

You passed a pointer to a local structure which would have catastrophic results in worst case, but in debug build you've ran afoul of exception - the function attempted to corrupt current stack frame.